# Determine the elements which an event has bubbled through

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, dom

Given a simplified document like this:

```
<div id="outerDiv">
    <div id="innerDiv">
        <input id="theInput" />
    </div>
</div>
```

If I were to click on `#theInput`, the click event would bubble up to `#innerDiv` and then `#outerDiv`. What I'd like to do would be to put a handler on `#outerDiv` to listen for those clicks, and then inspect the 'bubble-chain' to see which elements have previously received this same click event.

So, for example, clicking on `#theInput` the handler in `#outerDiv` would give me `[#outerDiv, #innerDiv, #theInput]`. If I were to click outside of `#theInput`, but still inside `#innerDiv` then the result would be `[#outerDiv, #innerDiv]`

*Just to clarify, the actual document is not as simple as this, and there could be any number of children or siblings at each level. Also, when I refer to `#theInput`, I'm referring to the element itself, that is, I'm not looking for an array of IDs. Lastly, given that there could be any number of elements, I'd like to avoid adding extra handlers to intermediate elements.*

jQuery is welcome in my house.

Comment: Can't you just get the ".parents()" list from the event target?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems like:

```
function myHandler(ev) {
  var $bubbleParents = $(ev.target).parents();

  // ...
}
```

is all you need, esp. if you're using jQuery and your event handlers will have `this` bound to the element relevant to the handler code.  The list of parents from the target will tell you all the elements that the event can possibly bubble to, and your `this` reference will be one of the elements in that list.  (I *think* the list of parents is in "inner-to-outer" order, but I'd have to check in a fiddle.)  Thus you can tell which elements have already been "visited" and which haven't.

Comment: You know sometimes when you have one of those "duhhhhh" moments? Yeah, that's me right now.

Comment: This doesn't work if the event target has been removed from the DOM after it triggered the event but before the event finished bubbling.

Any idea how that can be achieved?

Comment: @spinningarrow well if the object was somehow removed from the DOM between the time the event occurred and the point at which you check the target's parents, I'm not sure what you can do to find it. That seems like a fairly unusual situation.

Answer (score 2):

With the event object, use the target to find out the click element. From there you can use the parents() function in jQuery to find all the parents in the chain.

```
var parents;
handler = function(e){
 // specifying the limit node in parents
 parents = $(e.target).parents("#outerDiv");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('outerDiv').bind('click', function(e) {
    var current = e.target;
    var arrayClicked = new Array();
    arrayClicked[] = current;
    function test() {
        if(current.parent() == $('.outerDiv')) {
            return arrayClicked;
        } else {
            arrayClicked[] = current;
            current = current.parent();
            test();
        }
    }
    var yourdivs = test();
});
```

Comment: how about $(e.target).parents().andSelf()

Answer (score 0):

**using vanilla JS**

```
event.composedPath()

// based on question
let inner = document.getElementById("theInput");
inner.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  console.log(e.composedPath());
})
```